# Setting up JPA and hibernate - Schema-validation: missing table [TBL]

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to setup JPA with hibernate, and using JBoss to deploy. I am getting this error:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [TBL]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.validateTable(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:67)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.doValidation(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:50)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:91)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:473)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879)
```

But I do have a table called TBL in the database, created with this code:

```
create table TBL (id int not null auto_increment primary key);
```

I'm using mysql, and this is my persistence.xml file:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
  version="2.1">

  <persistence-unit name="unit1" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />

      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I do have `mysql-connector-java`, version 5.1.6 in the pom.xml file.

This is the java class for that table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TBL")
public class Tbl implements Serializable {
    public enum EnumName { /*...*/ }

    // private and public static final variables

    @Id
    private Long id;

    public Tbl() {}

    // some getters
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: When you connect to the database you can execute select * from TBL?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yes

Comment: Try changing validate to update and see what happens

Comment: @SimonMartinelli It doesn't show an error with a stack trace, but an INFO message saying "HHH000262: Table not found: TBL"

Comment: and when you run it again?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli the same. With "update", the message appears for all the tables, not just TBL.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli If I restart the server with the .war in the deployments folder, the message appears again. But if I put in the war while the server is started, the message doesn't appear. Why does this happen? Will I have to replace the war everytime I restart the server?